# fails every time i try to run. issue with text file creation?

Tags: java, text-files

need help with writing to and receiving from the text files
it seems to go almost all the way but then it says that no file exists,  at that point it should create one and then start writing to it.  it says that it failed to find one and then it just ends itself.  I don't know why

```
package sorting;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;

public class Sorting {

    private static int[] oneToFiftyThou = new int[50000];
    private static int[] fiftyThouToOne = new int[50000];
    private static int[] randomFiftyThou = new int[50000];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length>0) {
            if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("init")) {
                // initialize the 3 files
                // 1-50000 file1
                // 50000-1 file2
                // random 50000 file3
                initializeFiles();
                writeFiles();
            }
        } else {
            readFilestoArray();
            System.out.println(""+oneToFiftyThou[0] + " - " + 
                            oneToFiftyThou[oneToFiftyThou.length-1]);
            System.out.println(""+fiftyThouToOne[0] + " - " + 
                            fiftyThouToOne[fiftyThouToOne.length-1]);
            System.out.println(""+randomFiftyThou[0] + " - " + 
                            randomFiftyThou[randomFiftyThou.length-1]);
            intInsertionSort(oneToFiftyThou);
            intInsertionSort(fiftyThouToOne);
            intInsertionSort(randomFiftyThou);
        }

    }

    private static void initializeFiles() {
        //Array one
        for(int i=1; i<oneToFiftyThou.length+1; i++) {
            oneToFiftyThou[i-1] = i;
        }
        //Array two
        for(int i=50000; i>0; i--) {
            fiftyThouToOne[fiftyThouToOne.length-(i)] = i;
        }
        //Array Three Random. Copy Array one into a new Array and shuffle.
        System.arraycopy(oneToFiftyThou, 0, randomFiftyThou, 0, 
                                 randomFiftyThou.length);
        Random random = new Random();
        for(int i=randomFiftyThou.length-1; i>0; i--) {
            int index = random.nextInt(i+1);
            //Swap the values
            int value = randomFiftyThou[index];
            randomFiftyThou[index] = randomFiftyThou[i];
            randomFiftyThou[i] = value;
        }
    }

    public static void writeFiles() {

        ArrayList<int[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        arrayList.add(oneToFiftyThou);
        arrayList.add(fiftyThouToOne);
        arrayList.add(randomFiftyThou);

        int fileIter = 1;

        for(Iterator<int[]> iter = arrayList.iterator(); 
                                    iter.hasNext(); ) {
            int[] array = iter.next();
            try {
                File file = new File("file"+fileIter+".txt");

                //check for file, create it if it doesn't exist
                if(!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
                BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter
                                                                  (fileWriter);
                for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
                    bufferWriter.write(""+array[i]);
                    if(i!=array.length-1) {
                        bufferWriter.newLine();
                    }
                }
                bufferWriter.close();
                fileIter++;
            }catch(IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            } 
        }
    }

    public static void readFilestoArray() {
        ArrayList<int[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        arrayList.add(oneToFiftyThou);
        arrayList.add(fiftyThouToOne);
        arrayList.add(randomFiftyThou);

        int fileIter = 1;

        for(Iterator<int[]> iter = arrayList.iterator(); 
                                    iter.hasNext(); ) {
            int[] array = iter.next();
            try {
                File file = new File("file"+fileIter+".txt");

                //check for file, exit with error if file doesn't exist
                if(!file.exists()) {
                    System.out.println("file doesn't exist "
                                                            + file.getName());
                    System.exit(-1);
                }

                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
                BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader
                                                                  (fileReader);
                for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
                    array[i] = Integer.parseInt
                                                    (bufferReader.readLine());
                }
                bufferReader.close();
                fileIter++;
            }catch(IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            } 
        }
    }

    private static void intInsertionSort(int[] intArray) {
        int comparisonCount = 0;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i=1; i<intArray.length;i++) {
            int tempValue = intArray[i];
            int j = 0;
            for(j=i-1; j>=0 && tempValue<intArray[j];j--){
                comparisonCount++;
                intArray[j+1] = intArray[j];
            }
            intArray[j+1] = tempValue;
        }
        long endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Comparison Count = " + comparisonCount 
                           + " running time (in millis) = " + 
                                    (endTime-startTime) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `if(!file.exists())` conditional in the `readFilestoArray` method looks suspicious

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this issue? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

Well, works for me. Execute it in console like that:

`java Sorting init`

Then execute it another time:

`java Sorting`

Works perfectly. If you are in Eclipse go to run configuration > arguments and put `init` there.

Point is in your main method you are checking if someone invoked the program with `init` parameter, if yes then you create those files and write to them, if not - you are reading from them. You are probably invoking without `init` and the files are not there  yet, that's why it doesn't work.